# do upload file to access a web page? my code is bad?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

The idea is simple, when you access the same page web you should upload a different file according to the click on `<a>` elements : tracks or sets.

But my code does not work, some idea?

html in page web

```
<li id="sets"><a href="producciones.html" onclick="cargar('tracks.txt', '#p1')">Tracks</a></li>
<li id="sets"><a href="producciones.html" onclick="cargar('sets.txt', '#p1')">Sets</a></li>
```

JQuery+AJAX in script js.

```
function cargar(arch, id){
    $.ajax({
        url:arch,
        success:function(result){
            $(id).html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What error do you get? Check the console of the debugger tools (F12 on Chrome for example)

Comment: This is not a file upload. In uploads the client sends a file to the server.

Comment: pardon my expression, load a .txt sent from the client

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when the link is pressed, the function `cargar()` is executed, but also, the page is reloaded.
Try add `return false;` to block opening the page in the browser window.

```
<li id="sets"><a href="producciones.html" onclick="return cargar('tracks.txt', '#p1');">Tracks</a></li>
<li id="sets"><a href="producciones.html" onclick="return cargar('sets.txt', '#p1');">Sets</a></li>
```

And:

```
function cargar(arch, id){
  $.ajax({url:arch,success:function(result){
    $(id).html(result);
  }});
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but probe your example but does not work, yet I do not understand what the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem between href and inline JS `onclick`.

You could add a little bit more of JQuery to avoid inline script and do something like this :

```
<li id="sets-1" target="p1" url="tracks.txt">Tracks</li>
<li id="sets-2" target="p1" url="sets.txt">Sets</li>

$('[id^="sets-"]').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('url');
        var target = $(this).attr('target');
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            success:function(result){
                $('#' + target).html(result);
            }
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: gracias, pero  el link producciones.html para acceder donde iria? probando asi no funciona. <li class="sets" id="sets-1" target="p1" url="tracks.txt"><a href="producciones.html">Tracks</a></li>

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak spanish :o)

Comment: I don't understand where you want to go with producciones.html. The AJAX function is useless if you load a new page with <a> element.

Comment: sorry you, but the link producciones.html to access where joins? testing so it doesn't work.